# Weird artefact below x-axis; second half of standard form number? How do I get rid of this

Tags: pgfplots

I have a very small-scale graph, x values from 0 to 0.001

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

How do I get rid of that 10^-3?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        axis line style = {-},
        xlabel = $$,
        ylabel = $$,
        xmin = 0,
        xmax = 0.001,
        clip=false,
        xtick = {0, 0.001},
        xticklabels = {,},
        ymin = -1,
        ymax = 1,
        ytick = {-1,0,1},
        height = 10em,
        width = 30em,
      ]
      \addplot [
        ybar,
        fill=blue,
        bar width=0.000005,
        draw=none,
      ]
      coordinates {
        (0,0.00928)
        (0.00002083333,0.23672)
        (0.00004166667,0.31467)
        (0.0000625,0.58179)
        (0.00008333333,0.46774)
        (0.0001041667,0.71017)
        (0.000125,0.45074)
        (0.0001458333,0.61990)
        (0.0001666667,0.30692)
        % ... many more coordinates
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

There's 48 bars in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the manual, section 3.2.3, that is a scale tick.
It is there so that x ticks can be marked with short values like "1", "2"... instead of "0.001", "0.002"... by indicating that they are to be interpreted times 10^-3.
To remove it simply add `scaled x ticks=false` to the axis specification:

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = center,
    axis line style = {-},
    xlabel = $$,
    ylabel = $$,
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 0.001,
    clip=false,
    xtick = {0, 0.001},
    xticklabels = {,},
    ymin = -1,
    ymax = 1,
    ytick = {-1,0,1},
    height = 10em,
    width = 30em,
    scaled x ticks=false
  ]
```